# asp.net checkbox onchange javascript not working

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, checkbox

I have two checkboxes I want them to behave as radio buttons (When on is checked the other should be unchecked)

The following code isn't work properly.

HTML:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CHK_Reviewd" Checked="true" Visible="false" runat="server" />                   
<asp:CheckBox ID="CH_EmpReviewd"  runat="server" Text="" visible="false" />
```

JavaScript:

```
  $(document).on('ready', function () {
                var CH_EmpReviewd = '#<%= CH_EmpReviewd.ClientID %>';
                var CHK_Reviewd = '#<%= CHK_Reviewd.ClientID %>';
                $(CH_EmpReviewd).change(function () {
                    if (this.checked)
                        $(CHK_Reviewd).prop("checked", false);

                });
                $(CHK_Reviewd).change(function () {
                    if (this.checked)
                        $(CH_EmpReviewd).prop("checked", false);

                });
            })
```

I am using jquery 1.7

Comment: @DinoMyte it doesn't enter in .change function

Comment: Your jQuery selector is not going to find your checkbox.  Your variables will give you the client id, but you still need the # sign in your selector:
var CH_EmpReviewd = '#<%= CH_EmpReviewd.ClientID %>';

Comment: @TimSouthard When I check developer toolbar  CH_EmpReviewd had correct value

Comment: it has the correct value, but you can't use $("checkboxid") in jQuery.  The element has to be identified as a class or an ID using a period or a #.  Your checkbox would be $("#checkboxid").

Comment: @TimSouthard it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Change your selector to get the element by the ID.

From:

```
var CH_EmpReviewd = '<%= CH_EmpReviewd.ClientID %>';
var CHK_Reviewd = '<%= CHK_Reviewd.ClientID %>';
```

To:

```
var CH_EmpReviewd = $('#CH_EmpReviewd');
var CHK_Reviewd = $('#CHK_Reviewd');
```